# angular ui version 0.10.0 breaks ng-form validation inside a tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a strange issue when I upgrade angular ui version from 0.7 to 0.10.
I have an ng-form which is inside a tab, a button outside the tab which will become disabled when the form is invalid.  I have to put the button outside the tab in my situation.

It works under version 0.7, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbuM7ggc5UnafgH8aqpf?p=preview)

However, it does not work under version 0.10, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kr1V7tUT1CVkwy8hO0Ae?p=preview)

The only way I can make it work is to put the button inside the tab.  It seems that the new version of angular ui changed how the scope is working.

Anyone has idea how to fix it?  Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting one, I think. The older version probably wasn't all the way right, the submit button of a form should ideally be inside the form and not outside. If you notice in v0.7.0 if you move the button inside the form it still works

Comment: because of my page layout, my submit button will not reside in the tab. I think it is common situation that the submit button reside out side the form it submits.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is that in the new angular-ui version, every tab content resides
in each own new created child scope, so now changed values inside the tab scope (like myForm in your case) will not affect the parent scope.
I edited your plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/82Gk0e8ok3Jio29zuQQU?p=preview), so that the ng-model is now $parent.myForm, which means it will evaluate any changes made in the child scope (inside the tab) also in the outer scope.

Comment: your plnkr still use old version angular ui (0.7).  If I change to new version for your sample, it does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your plnkr, besides rename the form name from myForm to myFormValues, there is no other changes.  How do you make the form model in the parent scope?